# how to recover from chmod 777 -R /

Tags: imac, unix

So I ran sudo chmod 777 -R / on my iMac. Now it won't boot, and around 2 hours ago I restarted the system hoping to gain access to recovery mode, but the loading bar is stuck in the exact middle and has been for the last 2 hours. Can anyone help me?

I pretty much screwed over the permissions for every single file on my Mac.

Comment: Yes. What else did you think would happen? What model Mac, and what OS? Recovery should be unaffected. Did you hold down Command R at reboot? Can you try Internet Recovery?

Comment: Yes, I have tried holding command R at boot. I believe I have a 2017 21 inch iMac. I was running macOS Monterey.

Comment: I have made it into internet recovery! I don't want to get my hopes up, something could soft lock in here too, but I am in there.

Comment: MacOS Ventura is installing. All I really wanted to keep on my computer (which had 30gb left) was my chrome directory in application support, and I put that on a 16gb sandisk flash drive. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you just want to erase the disk, follow these instructions. Changing the attributes isn't useful for anything. https://support.apple.com/HT212749